# Error in Mob Spawning In Bukkit

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

Alright, So I had this problem on a project I've started in bukkit recently. As you will see I defined the head and everything, I set the owner of the head and applied it. But when I load in-game it shows normal Steve head! What i want it to do is when i execute the command "spawnmnz" It will spawn a minion with the sender/player's (In this case) head!

```
 package me.frostgamersa;

import net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.ItemSkull;
import org.bukkit.Location;
import org.bukkit.Material;
import org.bukkit.SkullType;
import org.bukkit.World;
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.entity.Zombie;
import org.bukkit.inventory.ItemStack;
import org.bukkit.inventory.meta.SkullMeta;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;



public class NewMinion extends JavaPlugin {
    String minion_name = "§3Minion §bSpawn §fEgg §8- §a[Spawned]";
    @Override
    public void onEnable() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onDisable() {

    }
     @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
     @Override
   public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, 
     String[] args) {
        Player player = (Player) sender;
        if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("spawnmnz")){
              World world = player.getWorld();
               Location loc = player.getLocation();


           ItemStack p_skull = new ItemStack(Material.SKULL_ITEM, 1, (short) 
           SkullType.PLAYER.ordinal());
            SkullMeta sm = (SkullMeta) p_skull.getItemMeta();
            sm.setOwner(player.getName());
            p_skull.setItemMeta(sm);

            Zombie minion = (Zombie) world.spawn(loc, Zombie.class);

            minion.setBaby(true);

            minion.setCustomName(minion_name);
            minion.setCustomNameVisible(true);

            minion.getEquipment().setHelmet(p_skull);





            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just for debugging purposes, adding it to your hand and placing it on the floor does what? Does it still not render as a player skull?

Comment: Indeed it does, but it's not used for such purposes in this plugin. I want it to render as a skull on the mob

Answer (score 0):

Get the skinvalue from the players profile and then set it on the skull item usin reflection, if it is not clear to you how to do this i will provide you a api for that ;)

Answer (score 0):

Does the server have an internet connection? It has to download the skin from the Mojang servers. Because of that, it might also just take a moment for the skin to appear on the head.

The import for the ItemSkull also seems weird, what server version do you use?